# Writing Unit testcases for eventHandler in powerBIEmbed in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, powerbi, react-testing-library, powerbi-embedded

I am using PowerBIEmbed from 'powerbi-client-react' library. **
https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-react ** . I want to write the unit testcases for the eventHandler used in PowerBIEmbed.Below is the sample code.

<PowerBIEmbed

```
    eventHandlers={
      new Map([
        ['loaded', () => console.log('Report content loaded, now rendering report.')],
        ['rendered', () => console.log('rendered')],
        ['error', (err: any) => {//some function here}]
      ])
    }
  />
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that, if it's already tested and implemented here. https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-react/blob/master/test/PowerBIEmbed.spec.tsx#:~:text=describe(%27tests%20for%20setting%20event%20handlers%27%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B

Comment: Reframe your question, what exactly you want, and if any additional scenarios you are writing testcase for, and errors if any you're facing ?

Comment: @KotanaSai I am using this library in my project, now I need to cover my code coverage for that component.

Comment: Ok, If I understand you correctly, you want to write testcases for EventHandlers ? You can take reference from the above link, where certain scenarios are implemented to test eventHandlers for component and using jasmine. You can write those in jest.

Comment: It will be good, if you clarify whether you are looking for scenarios to test eventHandlers, or facing issue with writing the code in jest for eventHandlers